# How to delete IE addressbar history on Vista/Win7?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, history, address-bar

First, here is a picture of what I see
http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/4797/iedrop.png

I need an solution to clear addressbar dropdawn, but not using ClearMyTracksByProcess or IE dialogs. I need to delete **only** a specific URL and all his traces.

I deleted manually all traces of that URL in:

1. Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files*
2. Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History*
3. Users\\Recent*

also that URL can be found in:

4) Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery\High

Now I made an BootTime program that searches for 8 and 16 bit charsets string in all my system disc files. URL wasn't found anywhere, but after logging and starting IE, the URL is still there. I suspect this is related to 4), but can't understand how.

Comment: I think this question is appropriate for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Since @ssianky was looking for (and then provided) a programatic solution, this question belongs on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution.

```
HRESULT CreateCatalogManager(ISearchCatalogManager **ppSearchCatalogManager)
{
    *ppSearchCatalogManager = NULL;

    ISearchManager *pSearchManager;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CSearchManager, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSearchManager));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSearchManager->GetCatalog(L"SystemIndex", ppSearchCatalogManager);
        pSearchManager->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

{

    ISearchCatalogManager *pCatalogManager;
    HRESULT hr = CreateCatalogManager(&pCatalogManager);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pCatalogManager->Reset();
        pCatalogManager->Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: This only removes stuff from url input field, do you know how to remove all history?

Answer (score 0):

Address bar urls are stored in the TypedUrls registry key.  See this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/typedurls.aspx) which claims to enum and delete them (I haven't tested it).

The History items in the dropdown are stored in the Url History database.  Use [IUrlHistoryStg::DeleteUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774953(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: That are not TypedUrls. TypedUrls can be seen on the first line in the picture and I know how to delete them from registry.

Comment: Oh, well, then.  Use IUrlHistoryStg.

Comment: IUrlHistoryStg::DeleteUrl() doesn't work too. It deletes VisitedUrls but not from addressbar.

Comment: IShellFolder/IEnumIDList interfaces on CSIDL_HISTORY deletes history too, but again not from addressbar

Comment: Well, that's the data source.  IE is probably caching them.  Are you restarting the browser?