# How to delete IE addressbar history on Vista/Win7?

Tags: internet-explorer, history, c++, api, address-bar

I asked same question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644668/how-to-delete-ie-addressbar-history-on-vista-win7).

First, here is a picture of what I see http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/4797/iedrop.png

I need an solution to clear addressbar dropdawn, but not using ClearMyTracksByProcess or IE dialogs. I need to delete only a specific URL and all his traces.

I deleted manually all traces of that URL in:

1. Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files*
2. Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History*
3. Users\user\Recent*

also that URL can be found in:

4) Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery\High*

Now I made an BootTime program that searches for 8 and 16 bit charsets string in all my system disc files. URL wasn't found anywhere, but after logging and starting IE, the URL is still there. I suspect this is related to 4), but can't understand how.

*PS: This IS NOT TypedUrls. I know where are and how to delete TypedUrls.*

Comment: I want this too. I believe this is possible in Firefox, to remove all history for one specific website. Would be a good feature to have in IE, but I dont think it exists.

Comment: Voting to close, as this doesn't really apply on SU, and you asked it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution.

```
HRESULT CreateCatalogManager(ISearchCatalogManager **ppSearchCatalogManager)
{
    *ppSearchCatalogManager = NULL;

    ISearchManager *pSearchManager;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CSearchManager, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSearchManager));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSearchManager->GetCatalog(L"SystemIndex", ppSearchCatalogManager);
        pSearchManager->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

{

    ISearchCatalogManager *pCatalogManager;
    HRESULT hr = CreateCatalogManager(&pCatalogManager);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pCatalogManager->Reset();
        pCatalogManager->Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you can see - at the far right side of the entry you want to get rid of - a red **X**.  Click that.  You will need to drop the list down the same way you did to make the screenshot first of course.

Comment: Well, i'm not blind... sure I know about that red X. I said "not using ClearMyTracksByProcess or **IE dialogs**"

Comment: @ssianky: Which just goes to show how important it is to be clear.  If you had said "without using IE itself" I wouldn't have bothered answering.  As it was, I was torn between wanting to help someone and wanting to avoid this exact situation in case your interpretation of "dialog" was not the same as mine.  For what it's worth, I don't consider a drop-down list to be a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Typed URLs

.

Comment: -1 The poster clearly states `PS: This IS NOT TypedUrls. I know where are and how to delete TypedUrls`.

Answer (score 0):

don not need to delete address bar history by going to C drive and remove from there in which you must have to follow the all the rite track. just download any history cleaner and just like antivirus scanner scan your browsing history.

Comment: This answer is right, but you should make it easier to understand.